# Vagrant can not create volume directories without sudo

Tags: macos, virtualbox, vagrant

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'hashicorp/precise64'...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/Users/foo/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-    precise64/1.1.0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "precise64_1397758443675_63113", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "9", "--disk", "/Volumes/untitled/precise64_1397758443675_63113/box-disk1.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /Users/foo/.vagrant.d/boxes/hashicorp-VAGRANTSLASH-precise64/1.1.0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the directory '/Volumes/untitled/precise64_1397758443675_63113' (VERR_ACCESS_DENIED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_IPRT_ERROR (0x80bb0005), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 779 of file     VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

Why is it having trouble creating the volume directories?

Comment: running ```vboxmanage list systemproperties``` shows ```/Volumes/untitled``` but running ```vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder default``` changes it to ```/Users/mm/VirtualBox```. now running vagrant up gives me a new error

Comment: ```Progress: 90%/Applications/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.5.3/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:214:in `initialize': Permission denied - /Users/mm/something/vagrant/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id (Errno::EACCES)```

Comment: chmod 777 on .vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/id and now vagrant up seems to be humming away happily.